# Combining Dijkstra's algorithm and A* search?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, a-star

Is it possible to combine Dijkstra's Algorithm and [A* search](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html)? How?

Comment: See also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56041

Answer (score 3):

Dijkstra's algorithm is just a special case of A* search where the heuristic function is 0. The less accurate the heuristic, the more A* behaves like Dijkstra's algorithm. You actually probably wouldn't want to combine them, since as long as you have an admissible heuristic A* will never expand more nodes than Dijkstra's algorithm. You'd only weaken the algorithm.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

but what it's your problem?..why you want to combine?
the A* search has a very expensive memory request, you can use the iterative-deeping A*.
for Dijkstra's algorithm you can use binary min-heap for implement the lowest priority queue